# How to cancel all unneccesary requests in vuex, axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, cancellation

I have a situation: when I live a page, async functions in `mounted` hook continue working (such as `await this.getUser({id: 1})`). I'm trying to use `axios.CancelToken`, but unfortunately it cancels only the first request (not all requested).
Send request function:

```
const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
const config = {
    headers: {
        authorization: `${prefix}${localStorage.getItem('authorization')}`
    },
    cancelToken: source.token
};
store.commit('SET_CANCEL_SOURCE', source);

const response = await axios.get(url, config);
```

Store mutations:

```
SET_CANCEL_SOURCE: (state, cancel: CancelTokenSource) => {
    state.cancelTokens.push(cancel);
},
RESET_CANCEL_TOKENS: (state) => {
    if (state.cancelTokens.length) {
        state.cancelTokens.map((item: any, index: number) => {
            console.log(index, item);
            item.cancel();
        });
        state.cancelTokens = [];
    }
}
```

Store action:

```
clearToken ({commit}) {
    commit('RESET_CANCEL_TOKENS');
}
```

And beforeUnmount for component:

```
beforeUnmount() {
    this.clearToken();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on the documentation, it seems to create a new token for each request. Maybe you need to use the *You can also create a cancel token by passing an executor function to the `CancelToken`*
https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation

Comment: @Patfreeze when doing like this - also only first request is cancelled

Comment: We only see one request in your POST do to add `config` to each request. Try to make your requests in one page without using `vuex` and see if only the first is cancelled.

Comment: I understood the reason: it cancels requests already added in request stack, but I have await in mounted, so that some requests are called after other are fullfilled. And those requests are not cancelled

Comment: Good, if you found the solution, POST it here as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that `CancelToken` cancels only those requests that are already sent.
The best solution I found is to make stages of loading information, create a variable, that represents the current stage and in `beforeUnmount` make variable `isCancelled = true`. So that next stages will not be excuted. Example:

```
data: () => ({
    stage: 0,
    isCancelled: false,
}),
async setInitialData() {
    if (this.stage >= 4 || this.isCancelled) {
        return;
    }

    switch (this.stage) {
        case 0:
            await action1();
            break;

        case 1:
            await action2();
            break;

        case 2:
            await action3();
            break;

        case 3:
            await action2();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    this.stage++;
    await this.setInitialData();
},
async mounted() {
    await this.setInitialData();
},
beforeUnmount() {
    this.isCancelled = true;
},
```